Complexity of the linear search of the several elements in the list
I'm doing a comparison between brute force search and my custom search approach.
A problem arose in estimating the complexity of a brute-force search. As part of the search, I need to check whether the specified elements are in an unsorted list of elements.
I will give a simplified example for a list of integers. I have an integer list with elements [1..100_000]. I go through all the elements linearly and calculate how many comparisons I need to do to find all the searched elements. For my case comparison is checking search.contains(values.get(i)) from the code example below.
My results are next:

For 1 searched element: near 50_000 comparisons, equals to O(N/2). It is clear to me. The best case is 1 the worst is 100_000, and the average is 50_000.
For 2 searched elements: near 65_000 comparisons. But why? What is mathematical formula or Computational complexity?
For 3 searched elements: near 75_000 comparisons. But why? What is mathematical formula or Computational complexity?

Screenshot of the my benchmark with 1_000 runs:

My code is next in Java.
I check the same elements, but the copy of the list is shuffled before each search.
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> values = IntStream.range(1, 100_000).boxed().toList();

        List<Integer> results1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> results2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> results3 = new ArrayList<>();

        Set<Integer> search1 = Set.of(1);
        Set<Integer> search2 = Set.of(1, 2);
        Set<Integer> search3 = Set.of(1, 2, 3);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            results1.add(search(values, search1));
            results2.add(search(values, search2));
            results3.add(search(values, search3));
        }
        System.out.println("Search 1: " + results1.stream().mapToInt(i->i).average().getAsDouble());
        System.out.println("Search 2: " + results2.stream().mapToInt(i->i).average().getAsDouble());
        System.out.println("Search 3: " + results3.stream().mapToInt(i->i).average().getAsDouble());
    }


    private static int search(List<Integer> list, Set<Integer> search) {
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(list);
        Collections.shuffle(values);

        int i = 0;
        int found = 0;
        for (; i < values.size(); i++) {
            if (search.contains(values.get(i))) {
                ++found;
            }
            if (found == search.size()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return i+1;
    }


In your comparison:
For 1 element, you observe around 50,000 comparisons which aligns with
O(N/2).
For 2 elements, you're seeing near 65,000 comparisons.
For 3 elements, you're seeing near 75,000 comparisons.
These results reflect the reduction in the remaining search space as each element is found and the remaining elements to be checked decrease, leading to a slightly smaller than theoretical average comparisons because the overlap (searching already checked elements) reduces the total search space more than theoretically accounted.
Computational Complexity
The complexity for searching k elements in an unsorted list of N elements in a brute-force manner can be considered as:
O(k.N/K+1)
Where:
k is the number of elements to search.
N is the size of the list.
For large N and small k, this approximates linear complexity O(N), but with the specific averages taken into account for each element search as described.
In one line we can say that :-
The average comparisons increase less sharply with each additional element because each search reduces the remaining list, which impacts the subsequent searches. This pattern is reflected in your empirical results and aligns with the expected behavior for linear search in an unsorted list.
